# How can i know the length of struct in golang?

Tags: go, struct

I am new to Golang and I am trying to get a number of attributes from a structure
For example:

```
type Client struct{
    name string//1
    lastName string//2
    age uint//3
}
func main(){
    client := Client{name:"Facundo",lastName:"Veronelli",age:23}
    fmt.println(client.getLengthAttibutes())//It would print "3" 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the reflect package's `ValueOf()` function returns a `value` struct. This has a method called [NumFields](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.NumField) that returns the number of fields.

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "reflect"
)

type Client struct{
    name string//1
    lastName string//2
    age uint//3
}

func main(){
    client := Client{name:"Facundo",lastName:"Veronelli",age:23}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(client)
    fmt.Printf("Struct has %d fields", v.NumField())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reflect` package for this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Client struct {
    name     string //1
    lastName string //2
    age      uint   //3
}

func main() {
    client := Client{name: "Facundo", lastName: "Veronelli", age: 23}
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(client).NumField())
}
```

This is not, however, the size of that struct, only the number of fields. Use `reflect.TypeOf(client).Size()` to get how many bytes the struct occupies in memory.